# Android Emulator 27.3.9: 'WHvGetCapability failed. hr=0x00000000 whpx_cap.HypervisorPresent? 0'

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator

Windows 10, on VS 15.8.4 with Android Emulator 27.3.9

Attempting to run the following command:

```
 .\Emulator -avd Android_Accelerated_X86_Oreo -partition-size 512 -verbose -show-kernel
```

Gives the following error:

```
Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
emulator: Checking whether Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) is available.
emulator: WinHvPlatform.dll found. Looking for WHvGetCapability...
emulator: WHvGetCapability found. Querying WHPX capabilities...
emulator: WHvGetCapability failed. hr=0x00000000 whpx_cap.HypervisorPresent? 0

emulator: WHPX is either not available or not installed.
emulator: CPU Acceleration: DISABLED
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: HAXM is not installed on this machine
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAXM is not installed on this machine
```

**Hyper-V** and **Windows Hypervisor Platform** are installed and working... Running **`(gcim Win32_ComputerSystem).HypervisorPresent`** returns **True**.

Here is the complete log:

```
emulator: Android emulator version 27.3.9.0 (build_id 4899998) (CL:e7b1c928a596dd490b990f4532055950f1409e49)
emulator: Found AVD name 'Android_Accelerated_X86_Oreo'
emulator: Found AVD target architecture: x86
emulator: argv[0]: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.exe'; program directory: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk/system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\

emulator: Probing for C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk/system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\/kernel-ranchu-64: file exists
emulator: Auto-config: -engine qemu2 (based on configuration)
emulator:  Found directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk/system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\

emulator: emuDirName: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk/system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\

emulator: Probing for C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk/system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\/kernel-ranchu-64: file exists
emulator: try dir C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator
emulator: Trying emulator path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64.exe'
emulator: Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64.exe
emulator: Adding library search path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator/lib64'
emulator: Adding library search path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader'
emulator: Adding library search path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator/lib64/gles_angle'
emulator: Adding library search path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator/lib64/gles_angle9'
emulator: Adding library search path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator/lib64/gles_angle11'
emulator: Adding library search path for Qt: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\lib64\qt\lib'
emulator: Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\lib64\qt\plugins
emulator: Setting Qt to use software OpenGL: QT_OPENGL=software
emulator: Quoted param: ["C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64.exe"]
emulator: Quoted param: [-avd]
emulator: Quoted param: [Android_Accelerated_X86_Oreo]
emulator: Quoted param: [-partition-size]
emulator: Quoted param: [512]
emulator: Quoted param: [-verbose]
emulator: Running :C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64.exe
emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] = ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64.exe""
emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "-avd"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[02] = "Android_Accelerated_X86_Oreo"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[03] = "-partition-size"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[04] = "512"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[05] = "-verbose"
emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
 '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64.exe"' -avd Android_Accelerated_X86_Oreo -partition-size 512 -verbose
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start

emulator: Android virtual device file at: C:\Users\rcarson.adm\.android\avd\Android_Accelerated_X86_Oreo.ini
emulator: virtual device content at C:\Users\rcarson.adm\.android\avd\Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: C:\Users\rcarson.adm\.android\avd\Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: C:\Users\rcarson.adm\.android\avd\Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: using snapshot lock path: C:\Users\rcarson.adm\.android\avd\Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo.avd/snapshot.lock
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 27
emulator: Read property file at C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk/system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\/build.prop
emulator: No boot.prop property file found.
emulator: 'magic' skin format detected: 768x1280
emulator: autoconfig: -skin 768x1280
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir (null)
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk/system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\/kernel-ranchu-64
emulator: Target arch = 'x86'
emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk/system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\/ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk/system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\/system.img
emulator: Using initial vendor image: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk/system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\/vendor.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data C:\Users\rcarson.adm\.android\avd\Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata C:\Users\rcarson.adm\.android\avd\Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache C:\Users\rcarson.adm\.android\avd\Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard C:\Users\rcarson.adm\.android\avd\Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Increasing RAM size to 1024MB
emulator: VM heap size 64MB is below hardware specified minimum of 256MB,setting it to that value
emulator: System image is read only
emulator: Found 4 DNS servers: 192.168.0.72 8.8.8.8 fec0:0:0:ffff::1 fec0:0:0:ffff::2
emulator: found magic skin width=768 height=1280 bpp=16

Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
emulator: Checking whether Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) is available.
emulator: WinHvPlatform.dll found. Looking for WHvGetCapability...
emulator: WHvGetCapability found. Querying WHPX capabilities...
emulator: WHvGetCapability failed. hr=0x00000000 whpx_cap.HypervisorPresent? 0

emulator: WHPX is either not available or not installed.
emulator: CPU Acceleration: DISABLED
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: HAXM is not installed on this machine
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAXM is not installed on this machine
```

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Comment: My cpu turned out not to be compatible